# Worklight adapter connecting to backend over SSL

Tags: worklight-adapters

WL 5.0.6, HTTP adapter, running on Liberty

We want to make simple connection from our adpater to a backend over SSL, the backend team have provided us their certificate.

Our symptom is

> FWLSE0101E: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

We have read the [infocenter here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_ibm_worklight_server_and_self-signed_certificates.html) but clearly have got something wrong. Steps we took

1. Used the JRE keystore tool to add the cert to a keystore.
2. Adjusted the worklight properties to point to the kaystore.
3. Restarted the WL Server

Any suggestions for how to diagnose or fix?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  We're having the same problem.

Comment: our issues were with our certificate, the hosts were not in our DNS server so we added entries to etc/hosts. I don't have the complete recipe we used I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you please write this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The issue in this case was that the certificate referenced hosts that were not visible to our DNS server. We worked around this by adding entries to /etc/hosts.